# Cakephp redirect is giving the error Call to a member function header() on null

Tags: php, cakephp

//awardscontroller

```
App::import('Controller', 'Permissions');
        class AwardsController extends AppController {
        public function add($id=NULL) {
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
            }
            if(!$this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));      
            }else{
                $Permission= new PermissionsController;
                if($Permission->isAuth($id)){
                    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                        $this->Award->create();
                        $this->request->data['Award'][0]['basicprofile_id']=10;
                        var_dump($this->data);
                        if ($this->Award->saveAll($this->request->data['Award'])) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Award has been added '));
                            //$Permission= new PermissionsController;
                            //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));
                            $Permission->redirectProfile($id);
                        } else {
                            $this->set('error',sizeof($this->request->data['Award']));
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The award has not added. Please, try again.'));
                        }   
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to access it'));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

//premissioncontroller

```
 <?php

        class PermissionsController extends AppController {


        public function redirectProfile($id){
            if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Admin'){echo "working";
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'index'));
            }else if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Teacher'){
                //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'profiles','action' => 'teacher', $id));
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

In permissioncontroller echo is printing but the rediection of url gives the fatal error: Call to a member function header() on null . Any Suggesstion

Comment: Does it print "working" ?

Comment: yeah its print working if $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'index')); is commented.

Comment: Tell us what happens if you put `if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Admin'){echo "working";
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'index'));
            }else if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Teacher'){
                //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'profiles','action' => 'teacher', $id));
            }`  code instead of `$Permission->redirectProfile($id);`  ? I mean replace it in current controller function itself .

Comment: its working and redirecting into the index of users controller. But I want to use this $Permission->redirectProfile($id); instead of if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Admin'){echo "working"; $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'index')); }else if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Teacher'){ //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'profiles','action' => 'teacher', $id)); }

Comment: In short you have to call function rather than writing same code again. Simple and short :) Correct?

Comment: thanks for your trick @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com . I came up with the the solution

Comment: Which solution you came up with ?

Comment: I guess this is problem with the cakephp. So Just return the url address to redirect and redirect it from the awardscontroller itself. :) :) .

Comment: Sachin, you are great ! **`:)`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the trick.
//awardscontroller

```
App::import('Controller', 'Permissions');
        class AwardsController extends AppController {
        public function add($id=NULL) {
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid User'));
            }
            if(!$this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));      
            }else{
                $Permission= new PermissionsController;
                if($Permission->isAuth($id)){
                    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                        $this->Award->create();
                        $this->request->data['Award'][0]['basicprofile_id']=10;
                        var_dump($this->data);
                        if ($this->Award->saveAll($this->request->data['Award'])) {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Award has been added '));
                            //$Permission= new PermissionsController;
                            //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));
                            $this->redirect($Permission->redirectProfile($id));
                        } else {
                            $this->set('error',sizeof($this->request->data['Award']));
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The award has not added. Please, try again.'));
                        }   
                    }
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to access it'));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

//permissioncontroller

```
<?php

  class PermissionsController extends AppController {
public function redirectProfile($id){
            if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Admin'){echo "working";
                return (array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'index'));
            }else if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Teacher'){
                return (array('controller'=>'profiles','action' => 'teacher', $id));
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Just return the url address to redirect and redirect it from the awardscontroller itself.